# Is there a way to disable the motion controls when connected to TV?

Tags: pokemon-lets-go

When you are connected to the television, it makes you actually *throw* the pokeball using motion controls with the detached controller.

I've tried attaching the controller to the grip that the Switch comes with, but nothing interesting happened.

Is there a way to disable this setting while connected to the TV or is there a (third party) controller that would work to play this game without motion controls?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it is impossible to disable motion controls while connected to the TV.

Additionally, the Pro controller doesn't work. You can get the Pokemon Plus controller, which is in the form of a Pokeball, but it also requires motion controls to operate.